# C# Regular Expression to return only the numbers

Tags: c#, regex

Let's say I have the following within my source code, and I want to return only the numbers within the string:

The source is coming from a website, just fyi, and I already have it parsed out so that it comes into the program, but then I need to actually parse these numbers to return what I want.  Just having a doosy of a time trying to figure it out tho :(

like:  13|100|0;

How could I write this regex?

```
    var cData = new Array(
        "g;13|g;100|g;0", 
        "g;40|g;100|g;1.37", 
        "h;43|h;100|h;0", 
        "h;27|h;100|h;0", 
        "i;34|i;100|i;0", 
        "i;39|i;100|i;0", 
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure you actually need regex here.

```
var str = "g;13|g;100|g;0";
str = str.Replace("g;", "");
```

would give you `"13|100|0"`.

Or a slight improvement on spinon's answer:

```
// \- included in case numbers can be negative.  Leave it out if not.
Regex.Replace("g;13|g;100|g;0", "[^0-9\|\.\-]", "");
```

Or an option using split and join:

```
String.Join("|", "g;13|g;100|g;0".Split('|').Select(pipe => pipe.Split(';')[1]));
```

Comment: the only issue is that i dont always know what that first letter will be in each pipe.  That's why i think i need a regex.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like this so you only keep numbers and separator:

```
Regex.Replace("g;13|g;100|g;0", "[^0-9|]", "");
```

Comment: I think the `|` character needs to be escaped, and this would strip out the decimal in the second example, too.

Comment: @Andrew You are right. You know since all the other options looked all the same I didn't even notice the decimal in that second one. I forgot about the escape in the pipe. I actually tested in a simple regex tester I have that I didn't think about it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Regex might be overkill in this case. Given the uniform delimiting of `|` and `;` I would recommend `String.Split()`. Then you could either split again or use `String.Replace()` to get rid of the *extra* chars (i.e. `g;`).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a number of solutions, but I'll throw in one more where you can iterate over each group in a match to get the number out if you want.

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\w;([\d|.]+)\|?");
Match matchResults = regexObj.Match("g;13|g;100|g;0");
if( matchResults.IsMatch )
{
   for (int i = 1; i < matchResults.Groups.Count; i++) 
   {
      Group groupObj = matchResults.Groups[i];
      if (groupObj.Success) 
      {
         //groupObj.Value will be the number you want
      } 
   }
}
```

I hope this is helps.